# How to uninstall software installed via Terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-uninstall

I installed software using the `sudo apt-get install [program name]` command in the Terminal.

How should I go about uninstalling said program via. Terminal?

What should I specifically type in the Terminal?

- The program does not appear in the Installed tab of Software Center
- It exists in the Software Center, but according to Center it hasn't been installed
- The program operates fine though when installed using above command

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
sudo apt-get remove nameOfProgram
```

Or if you want to uninstall the program and also associated data:

```
sudo apt-get purge nameOfProgram
```

That will remove the program. It doesn't always remove the dependencies that were installed to make the program work. To clean up those package you can run this after:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Do I write the name of the program after the `autoremove` in `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: do remove first then do autoremove

Comment: After doing `sudo apt-get remove nameOfProgram` this is the output: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'freecad' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`

Comment: run 'apt list --installed' (shows all installed) and scroll through the list and see if you see a variation on that name in the list.

Comment: As far as I can see, there isn't. However when I Search my computer and type the program name it still shows up. There is still the .dsk file in Files.

Comment: I updated answer, try reinstalling and use purge instead of remove. That deletes the program and also any data that goes with it.

Comment: Would that be `sudo apt-get purge [nameofApp]`?

Comment: yep but it will only work if you install it again first

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Something went wrong with your edit, both command-lines are the same, looks like you want to use `purge` in the second one...

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package [programName]`